# React Navigation to replace components completely

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm stark new to React, thus the question.
I've to programmatically switch between Login Screen and Sign Up screen in React. This is the design.

I've to transition from this, 
[image]

To this,

[image]

These are my components,

```
const Login = () => (
    <div className="login">
        <input className="top" placeholder="Email"/>

        <input className="bottom" placeholder="Password"/>
        <p>Forgot Password?</p>
        <button>Log In</button>

        <div className="imageholder">
            <img src={OrImage} alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div className="heading">
            <h1>Don't have an account yet?</h1>
        </div>



    </div>

);

export default Login

const Register = () => (
    <div className="register">

        <input className="top" placeholder="Full Name"/>

        <input className="bottom" placeholder="Username"/>

        <input className="bottom" placeholder="Email"/>

        <input className="bottom" placeholder="Mobile number"/>

        <input className="bottom" placeholder="Password"/>

        <input className="bottom" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>


        <button>Sign Up</button>

        <div className="imageholder">
            <img src={OrImage} alt=""/>
        </div>


    </div>
);
export default Register
```

And this is the holding container with the routes,

```
const FormHolder = () => (
    <div className="formholder">

        <section className="heading">
            <h1>Enter the world's first </h1>
            <h1>one-stop platform for football fans</h1>
        </section>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <section className="swappable">

            <Route path="/" render={() =>  <Login title="Login"/> }/>
            <Route path="/register" render={() => <Register title="Sign Up"/>}/>
            <NavLink to="/"><button className="registerButton">Sign Up </button></NavLink>

        </section>
        </BrowserRouter>


    </div>
);

export default FormHolder
```

The issue is that this doesn't even do the route correctly. Additionally I've the following questions.
I want to replace the Sign Up button with the smaller LogIn button when the component get's replaced. I'm not sure how I can do this with React Routing.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you're missing "exact" in your route. Try this "<Route exact path="/" render={() =>  <Login title="Login"/> }/>"

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 'Switch' and 'exact' in your implementation of routes.
Routes should be implemented like:

```
<section className="swappable">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() =>  <Login title="Login"/> }/>
      <Route path="/register" render={() => <Register title="Sign Up"/>}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
</section>
```